# How to decrypt Triple DES in Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, node-crypto

This code worked for me to encrypt, but how can I reverse it?

I have hashed the password in the database and I need to decrypt. I have both a key and a hash.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const md5 = text => {
  return crypto
    .createHash('md5')
    .update(text)
    .digest();
}

const encrypt = (text, secretKey) => {
  secretKey = md5(secretKey);
  console.log(secretKey.toString('base64'));
  secretKey = Buffer.concat([secretKey, secretKey.slice(0, 8)]); // properly expand 3DES key from 128 bit to 192 bit

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3', secretKey, '');
  const encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');

  return encrypted + cipher.final('base64');
};
const encrypted = encrypt('testtext', 'testkey');

console.log(encrypted);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do what you need. We'll create a decrypt function that decrypts using the same algorithm (and key obviously!):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const md5 = text => {
return crypto
    .createHash('md5')
    .update(text)
    .digest();
}

const encrypt = (text, secretKey) => {
    secretKey = md5(secretKey);
    console.log(secretKey.toString('base64'));
    secretKey = Buffer.concat([secretKey, secretKey.slice(0, 8)]); // properly expand 3DES key from 128 bit to 192 bit

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3', secretKey, '');
    const encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');

    return encrypted + cipher.final('base64');
};

const decrypt = (encryptedBase64, secretKey) => {
    secretKey = md5(secretKey);
    secretKey = Buffer.concat([secretKey, secretKey.slice(0, 8)]); // properly expand 3DES key from 128 bit to 192 bit
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede3', secretKey, '');
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedBase64, 'base64');
    decrypted += decipher.final();
    return decrypted;
};


const encrypted = encrypt('testtext', 'testkey');
console.log("Decrypted text:", decrypt(encrypted, 'testkey'));
```

Comment: No problemo! Glad to help :-)